# Link button onClick not working in React, css to change button to a link?

Tags: css, button, hyperlink, react-redux, onclick

I have a button in React which when clicked scrolls the page to the desired location, which is working.

```
<div className={styles.classB}>
     <Button onClick={ScreenMover.MoveToElem} > Extras </Button>
</div>
```

But I wanted the same onClick feature without a button, say a link and when clicking it should do the same operation. So I have used the below Link button, but it is not taking the onClick instead it goes to the page top based on the to="" attribute.

```
<div className={styles.classL}>
     <Link className={styles.linkButton} onClick={ScreenMover.MoveToElem} to=""> Extras </Link>
</div>
```

Another thought, if we can not achieve the above one, then can we have a button look like a link by applying some css style to the button? I should be able to override the inherited button styles and instead it should take the link look and feel. Is it possible and can we have a sample css class for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Link object is important for you?

If not you can use a simple `<p>` tag and the onClick event will working perfectly.

```
<p className={styles.linkButton} onClick={ScreenMover.MoveToElem}> Extras </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The Link object is not important for me. And the onClick works perfect with <p>. But how do we give the link features like underline and mouse over hand when mouse over this element only?

Comment: You can reach this result with CSS.

Add this css class to the object.
`.plink {
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}`